# Conditionals in where hash in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm

I have a query that looks like this:

```
 User.includes(:notifications).where({:type => 'Nice', :notifications => {:name =>'Weekly email'} })
```

How can I modify this query so that in the where, the :type can be 'Nice', 'nice', 'nicely', 'good' ?

How can I put an OR there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array in the condition to test several values:

```
User.includes(:notifications).where({:type => ['Nice', 'nice', 'nicely', 'good'], :notifications => {:name =>'Weekly email'} })
```

It will generate an SQL request with an `IN` clause.

Answer (score 4):

this is how you do it

`User.includes(:notifications).where({:type => ['Nice','nice','nicely','good'], :notifications => {:name =>'Weekly email'} })`

good luck!